# How to access an enum through an array object instance of a class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, oop, enums

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to access an enum that is declared within a class through an array object of the class...so far, I'm unable to access it. Here is an illustration.

```
class MyClass
{
    public enum gender { male, female };
    MyClass[] cs = new MyClass[];
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
    {
        cs[i].gender = male; //I cant do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is have an *instance* -- per se -- or rather 'value' of your `Gender` enum in your class, e.g. `MyGender`.  Also, you can't use a `for` loop just in a class body; it needs to be in a method:

```
class MyClass
{
    public Gender MyGender { get; set; }
    public enum Gender { male, female }    
    private static MyClass[] cs = new MyClass[];

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
        {
            cs[i].MyGender = MyClass.Gender.male; 
        }
    }
}
```

Also, enums should be named using [Pascal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break apart some of your stuff here. You are trying to doing loops inside of a class when this is not valid. You can copy and paste the below code into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) to try it out.

Below is a basic example of the Enum, Class and where the class is used separated in a reusable manner.

```
void Main()
{
    const int arraySize = 10;
    MyClass[] classes = new MyClass[arraySize];
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 2) == 0)
        {
            classes[i] = new MyClass { Gender = Gender.Male };
        }
        else
        {
            classes[i] = new MyClass { Gender = Gender.Female };
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < classes.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(classes[i].ToString());
    }

}

public class MyClass
{
    //Other properties here
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    //Constructors

    //Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {

        //Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx
        return $"{nameof(MyClass)} has a Gender of { Gender }";

        /*
           If no C# 6 then make your return statement this.
           return string.Format("{0} has a Gender of {1}", typeof(MyClass).Name, Gender);
        */
    }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

Output:

```
MyClass has a Gender of Male
MyClass has a Gender of Female
MyClass has a Gender of Male
MyClass has a Gender of Female
MyClass has a Gender of Male
MyClass has a Gender of Female
MyClass has a Gender of Male
MyClass has a Gender of Female
MyClass has a Gender of Male
MyClass has a Gender of Female
```

Comment: What does return $"***" mean in C#?

Comment: It's called string interpolation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: Oh, can't we use it until VS2015? I tried .net 4.0 VS2013, but not compile.

Comment: Then to get the same thing in non C# 6 you would use string.Format("{0} has a Gender of {1}", typeof(MyClass).Name, Gender)

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you've written your gender enum, when a new instance of MyClass is created the Gender property (I had to add this) will automatically be set to male.

So, if what you are trying to do is initialize cs once and only once (otherwise you'll get a stack overflow, make cs static and use a static constructor.

**EDIT**

Didn't have MAX being utilized when the array was declared and initialized in my first answer post.

```
public class MyClass
{
    const int MAX = 10;

    public enum gender { male, female }
    public gender Gender;
    static MyClass[] cs = new MyClass[MAX];

    static MyClass()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            cs[i] = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record I wouldn't code it this way for anything I was working on myself.  This is just to give an answer to the OP in the most expedient way possible.